# Apply CSS to ASP.Net webpage which includes the default master page

Tags: css, master-pages

In have created a new simple ASP.Net Web Application, in the Default.aspx file added new div as below

```
<div id="TestDiv"> Hi, This is CSS test. </div>
```

And for styling the above div, added below css in Site.css file

```
#TestDiv{ color:Red; }
```

If I check the Default.aspx page in Design view, found that the above text color is changed to Red.
But when I ran this application and check in browser, found that color is not changed and css is not applied to it.
I want to use the same Site.css which is declared in master page to be applied for the above div and I don't want to declare css style explicitly in Default.aspx page.
Could you please help me out how can I make it work.

Sharing Site.css content on request

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue" , "Lucida Grande" , "Segoe UI" , Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color: #3a4f63;
    width: 100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline
{
    display: inline;
}

legend
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#TestDiv
{
    color:Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reason of it not working is Directory Structure , which is making the CSS not reachable from your Default.aspx . otherwise there is no reason why it will not WORK. You can use the IE developer tool by pressing F12 and select the div and see if your site.css is applied or not. You also see the view source and copy the CSS path in the browser to see if it renders or not or your are getting 404

Comment: Here I am not creating any new page to think of Directory Structure, using the auto generated Default.aspx page which is working with Site.css stylesheet - I just added a new div to it and applying style to it in the same Site.css stylesheet. In browser I observed that the style is inherited from body of Site.css stylesheet. But here I want to use Site.css stylesheet only, please suggest me how could I make it work?

Comment: Can u share your site.css content

Comment: See i do not see that you are doing any wrong here , make sure that css file is not cached one , by just checking the name of the file and can you tell by using F12 what css class name is applied to your new DIV. Adding the screenshot will be great

Comment: Yes, I observed that the css file is cached one due to which the css is not applied to div. In browser I have selected all checkboxes and deleted everything in "Delete Browsing History" window, now the css is applying correctly. Thank you. But everytime I cannot delete the cache in browser right, how I need to fix this in code so that the css file is not cached one and css apply correctly.

Comment: You can use the version number like style.css?v=01. Because of querystring as you will change to style.css?v=02 it will be loaded by the browser again. Or you can append the file modified timestamp in the file , so any time you change the CSS file it will create new name style0110111.css

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you made a  tag that containing your currect css file location, and your link tag have to be on header but the div part has to be on body.

Comment: In Masterpage it is declared as below <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

Comment: And div part is in Deafult.aspx page body tag only

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this issue.  It's always best to use a browser's dev tools to see what is actually being affected by your front-end changes.  Chrome offers the absolute best suite for debugging...just right-click on your page and select "Inspect Element" on your div.

As for the specifics of this problem:

- Check to see you have referenced Site.css specifically.
- Ensure there are no other parent css definitions overriding yours
- If there is a conflict (eg: a "div" definition for color), make sure your css ID definition comes AFTER it in the page flow

Alternative options:

- Define CSS on a per-page basis using script closures.
- Use inline styling for the particular element.

**Response To Comments**

Well, every browser has default rules that are assigned to the majority of elements.  If you find a style that has been inherited from the body, it's likely due to a css "reset" stylesheet and/or schema where body has been given more reasonable default values.  I doubt you'll even find that in an ASP.NET application.

I would suggest creating your own stylesheet and referencing it in your default.aspx page.  It doesn't actually matter (so long as you reference YOUR stylesheet AFTER the GENERATED stylesheet) but it keeps everything separate.  You don't have a need to change the generated CSS for the most part.

Comment: Here I am not creating any new page to think of Directory Structure, using the auto generated Default.aspx page which is working with Site.css stylesheet - I just added a new div to it and applying style to it in the same Site.css stylesheet. In browser I observed that the style is inherited from body of Site.css stylesheet. But here I want to use Site.css stylesheet only, please suggest me how could I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Got 2 answers for you:

1. Tell me where your deafult.aspx file is located? inside a follder something like site/asp/deafult.aspx and your style is in site/style/site.css, if it does then add in link tag `<link href="../Style/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
2. If your website is in Site/deafult.aspx and css is in Site/Styles/Site.css then make sure the different bettwen the big and small words are same.